# Troubleshooting jasmine tests for angular controller

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a controller for a simple to-do app that does 2 things, (1) Query a database, and (2) post new functions a the database. The controller works fine but I'm trying to implement jasmine tests now and I'm having trouble getting the tests set up properly. I'd like to test that a new item is created and saved to the DB, but before I can even get to that part my tests are failing because of undefined variables and the controller doesn't seem to be able to get anything from the DB - It always returns an empty array. Here's my test:

```
describe('TodoListController', function() {

beforeEach(module('TodoApp'));

var $controller;    
var $scope;
var Dates;

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _Dates_, _$controller_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    Dates = _Dates_;
    $controller = _$controller_;
}));

describe('$scope.postTodo', function() {    

    it('creates a new todo item', function() {

        var controller = $controller('TodoListController', { $scope: $scope });

        var item = {
            date: "2015-02-17",
            day: "Tuesday",
            new_todo: "Make breakfast for everyone"
        }

        // testDateList = Dates.query({related:'True'});
        // console.log(testDateList); This returns an empty array

        // $scope.postTodo(item); Test fails because "theDate" is undefined

    });

});

});
```

And this is the corresponding controller

```
app.controller('TodoListController', function($scope, Todos, Dates) {

$scope.dateList = Dates.query({related:'True'});

$scope.postTodo = function(item) {

    if(item) {

        var theDate = _.findWhere($scope.dateList, {date: item.date});

        var todo_item = {
            todo: item.new_todo,
            position: 0,
            date: theDate.id
        }

        var newTodo = new Todos(todo_item);

        newTodo.$save().then(function(result) {

            console.log(result);

        }).then(function() {

            // Update your view....
            // console.log('success');
            theDate.todos.push(newTodo);
            theDate.new_todo = null;

        }, function(failure) {

            console.log('failure', failure);
            // Bring up a notice

        });

    }

};

});
```

**edit**

I started taking a part of the controller code while running the tests and I think it has something to do with the Dates query not running. Am I injecting this into the test improperly?

Comment: Is Dates.query({related:'True'}); an async ajax call?

Comment: I think it might be. This is from ngResource and the documentation says that calls return an empty array until it is populated

Comment: Then that would be the issue. You need to use jasmine async capabilities. Just add the done parameter to the it function